# PHPStorm has no PHP intepreters being listed

Tags: xdebug, phpstorm

I used to be able to run X-debug (I think on PHPStorm 5) - now several months later I'm trying to debug again and have run into an issue where I need to set my Interpreter in order to start debugging.

[image]

I develop on a remote host (via Samba) so there is no PHP executable to map a path to. Should I be seeing something in the dropdown list, as per [this screenshot](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Installing+and+Configuring+XAMPP+with+PhpStorm+IDE#InstallingandConfiguringXAMPPwithPhpStormIDE-IntegratingXAMPPwiththeIDE)?

**What do I need to do in order to see a PHP 5.x interpreter appearing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to configure the interpreter if you are not debugging local PHP scripts and not trying to use PHP provided web server. When debugging remote sites, xdebug running on the server connects back to PhpStorm.

> What do I need to do in order to see a PHP 5.x interpreter appearing?

You need PHP installed locally on your machine where PhpStorm is running and specifying the path to `php.exe` in the dialog under <kbd>...</kbd> button.

Comment: After restarting the IDE this morning - the debugger tool now pops up correctly